# Get a timer with less than 60 seconds?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I`m currently trying to obtain a `CountDownTimer` based on the time in milliseconds of a `Calendar` object. The `startTimer` function works, so does the `timerSort` function. The thing is that when the timer gets initialized with the `timeLeft` value, it never start from a value lower than 60 seconds. This eventually causes delays bigger than 10 seconds. any suggestions?

Thank you.
Code:

```
 private void startTimer(String x){
        counter = new CountDownTimer(timeLeft,1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                timeLeft = millisUntilFinished;
                updateCountdownText();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                timerRunning = false;
                int comp = Integer.parseInt(x);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Alarm received!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                cal[comp].add(Calendar.MINUTE,rec[comp]);

                //Update txt file
                int month = cal[comp].get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
                int day = cal[comp].get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                String data = cal[comp].get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ","
                        +cal[comp].get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ","
                        +day+ "," + month + ","
                        +cal[comp].get(Calendar.YEAR) + "," + rec[comp] + ",";
                try {
                    FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file[comp], false);
                    try {
                        stream.write(data.getBytes());
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                //end update
                timerSort();
                BluetoothGattCharacteristic C = btper.getCharacteristic(UUID.fromString("6E400001-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E"),UUID.fromString("6E400002-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E"));
                //If device is disconnected => it will crash
                btper.writeCharacteristic(C , x.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), WriteType.WITH_RESPONSE);
                speak(String.valueOf(comp+1));
            }
        }.start();
    }

    private void updateCountdownText() {
        if(counterView.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE)
        counterView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        int minutes = (int)timeLeft / 1000 / 60;
        int seconds = (int)timeLeft /1000 % 60;
        String timeLeftFormatted = String.format(Locale.getDefault(),"Time left until next pill: %02d:%02d",minutes,seconds);

        if(timeLeftFormatted.contains("00:00"))
            counterView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        counterView.setText(timeLeftFormatted);
    }

    private void resetTimer(){}

    private void timerSort(){
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        int i,j;
        j = 0;
        int fileindex = 0;
        int hour, day, month, minute, year;
        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        timeLeft = 0;



        for (i = 0; i<20; i++){
            fileindex = i+1;
            file[i] = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath(),"pills"+fileindex+".txt");
            cal[i] = (Calendar) calendar.clone();
            //Read text from pills file
            StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

            try {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file[i]));
                String line;

                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    text.append(line);
                    text.append('\n');
                }
                br.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                //You'll need to add proper error handling here
            }
            String str = text.toString();
            List<String> elephantList = Arrays.asList(str.split(","));
            hour = Integer.parseInt(elephantList.get(0));
            minute = Integer.parseInt(elephantList.get(1));
            day = Integer.parseInt(elephantList.get(2));
            month = Integer.parseInt(elephantList.get(3));
            year = Integer.parseInt(elephantList.get(4));
            rec[i] = Integer.parseInt(elephantList.get(5));
            cal[i].set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
            cal[i].set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
            cal[i].set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
            cal[i].set(Calendar.MONTH-1, month);
            cal[i].set(Calendar.YEAR,year);
        }
//        sorting:
        int letsgo = 0;
        Calendar tudor = Calendar.getInstance();
        tudor.set(Calendar.YEAR,calendar.getMaximum(Calendar.YEAR));
        for (i = 0; i<20; i++){
            if(tudor.after(cal[i]) && cal[i].after(calendar)){
                tudor = cal[i];
                letsgo = i;
            }
        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(letsgo), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        TextView nextPillView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nextPillView);
        if (!cal[letsgo].after(calendar)) {
            nextPillView.setText("No Pills Scheduled");
        } else {

//            timeLeft = cal[letsgo].getTimeInMillis() - calendar.getTimeInMillis() - Calendar.MILLISECOND;
            int secleft = cal[letsgo].get(Calendar.SECOND)-calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
            int minleft = cal[letsgo].get(Calendar.MINUTE)-calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            timeLeft = secleft*1000 + minleft*60*1000 ;
            //timeLeft = cal[letsgo].getTimeInMillis() - calendar.getTimeInMillis();
            String theTime = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d", cal[letsgo].get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), cal[letsgo].get(Calendar.MINUTE));
            month = cal[letsgo].get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
            nextPillView.setText(cal[letsgo].get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)+":"+cal[letsgo].get(Calendar.MINUTE)+ " | | Day: " + cal[letsgo].get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + " | | Month: " + String.valueOf(month) + " | | Year: " + cal[letsgo].get(Calendar.YEAR));
            startTimer(String.valueOf(letsgo));
        }
    }
    private void speak(String x){
        float pitch = 1;
        float speed = 1;
        mTTS.setPitch(pitch);
        mTTS.setSpeechRate(speed);
        mTTS.speak("It is time to administer the compartment with the lit LED",
                TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD,null);

    }
```

Comment: I suggest you use `LocalDateTime` or something else from the `java.time` package, instead of `Calendar`.

Comment: Apart from starting the timer, ‘’’timeLeft’’’ is also used to update the countdown view